# Adding area code "84" only to phone numbers missing an area code in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to clean up some data. The phone number column (int64) for
some employees have the area code while the area code is missing in the phone
numbers for the other employees. Is there some method,
that I can use to add the area code (84) before the number to only those phone numbers that
are missing the area code? Secondly, I want to remove '+' sign in front of all numbers.

I'm using Python. The column looks like this:

Mobile

84333605993

973444062 ---- add 84

84339769174

+84349251856---- remove +

Comment: What have you tried until now. Please add the code to post @D Alam

Comment: You can know if a phone number has area code added to it by knowing the length of the phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
phone_number = phone_number.replace("+","")
if (len(phone_number)==9)
    phone_number = "84" + phone_number
```

First you can replace '+' with nothing and then you check if phone_number has 9 digits. If so, you add the area code. phone_number is a variable I choose to contain  telephone number. Now you have to use probably for method to apply it on all your list ( You did not mention how you store this values). In case of pandas, you can do a function out of it and apply it to whole column.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['84333605993', '973444062', '84339769174', '+84349251856'], columns=['Mobile'])

df['Mobile'] = df['Mobile'].str.replace('+', '')
df.loc[~df['Mobile'].str.startswith('84'), 'Mobile'] = '84' + df[~df['Mobile'].str.startswith('84')]['Mobile']

df
```

```
    Mobile
0   84333605993
1   84973444062
2   84339769174
3   84349251856
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will

- Remove the `+` if it exists at the beginning of the phone number
- If the length of the phone number is equal to 9, then add the area code (84) to it.

```
def clean_phone_number(n):
    n = n.replace('+', '')
    # Add the area code 84 if len(n) == 9
    if len(n) == 9:
        n = '84' + n
    return n


print(clean_phone_number('952368741'))
print(clean_phone_number('+84475968475'))
print(clean_phone_number('84456968475'))
```

```
Output

84952368741
84475968475
84456968475
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code snippet should do the trick:

```py
numbers = ['84333605993',
           '973444062',
           '84339769174',
           '+84349251856']
corrected = []
for number in numbers:
    number = number.strip('+')  # removes +
    if len(number) == 9:
        number = '84' + number  # adds 84
    corrected.append(number)
print(corrected)
```

```py
Output:
['84333605993', '84973444062', '84339769174', '84349251856']
```